# Ionic 2 / Angular 2 providers cannot be resolved

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, angular2-providers

I am using Ionic 2 and have some problems with providers/injections since version 2.0.0.
The error I keep getting is the following (with different providers, not only this one):

> Uncaught Error: 
>   Can't resolve all parameters for LoginRedirectService: (App, ?, AlertController).

There seems to be a problem with resolving injections of my providers, even though they are all decorated with @Injectable.

one file

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginRedirectService {

    constructor(
        public app:App, 
        //another provider, needed within this one - this cannot be resolved
        public authService: AuthenticationService,
        public alert:AlertController
    )
//...
}
```

different file

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
    constructor(public dataService:DataService){
        //...
    }
}

//...
```

and so on.

I also have added all providers in the app.module.ts, in the order in which they have to be injected in:

```
//Ordered by dependencies, bottom is the most dependent on others
providers: [
    HttpModule,
    JsonpModule,
    RssService,
    EmergencyEmailService,
    InAppBrowserService,
    ExternalBrowser,
    AppLauncherService,
    LauncherPlaner,
    LauncherSkype,
    ConnectivityService,
    MockRemoteDataService,
    SoniaMirthRemoteDataService,
    DataService,
    AuthenticationService,
    LoginRedirectService,
    NewsStreamService,
    SoniaBootstrapService
]
```

My project structure looks like this:

- src

  - app

    - app.module.ts
    - app.component.ts
  - assets
  - pages
  - providers

    - sub-folders
  - ...
- package.json etc.

I have tried explicitly calling @Inject in the constructors of classes where they are needed, but no success either.

I am really out of ideas what to do and appreciate any help, thanks

Comment: Is `AuthenticationService` or `DataService` dependent on `Http`? The `HttpModule` and `JsonpModule` should go in the `@NgModule.imports` not `providers`. If you don't already have it in the `imports`, and the service _is_ dependent on `Http`, that _would_ cause this error

Comment: Thanks, I did remove them from there, but they were already added in imports, and it did not solve the issue.

Comment: I had the same issue. In my case one Provider was importing the other though this doesn't seem to be the case here. Just my two cents in case someone else bumps here like I did :)

Answer (score 0):

modules are not providers they reside in imports. Try above given by @peeskillet

Comment: Fixed that, thanks, but still getting the same error.

Comment: without any parameter is it working ? such as no injectors in constructor

Comment: Yes without the "?" parameter it is working, but the services are useless of course